# Is a larger buffer size better for a socket read loop executing in an ASP.NET Web Role?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, sockets, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is an Azure Web Role.  It talks to another system over a socket.  The files returned by the remote server are on average 100,000 bytes in length.

Currently I am using a 1024 byte buffer in a read loop when reading data from the socket (see code below).  I am not sure if it matters, but both systems are in the same Cloud Service with the same data centre affinity.

Would I be better off changing the size of the buffer to 100,000 bytes?  Or would that put more of a load on the server, especially if a large number of sessions were in progress?  Speed is the ultimate consideration here.

```
byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

// Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
do
{
    numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

    // Append the new bytes to our memory stream.
    memStream.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
}
while (myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the buffer array size offers diminishing returns. It does slightly impact the amount of memory used by your application: larger buffers held in memory take up more space. However, all that the buffer really serves to do is take bytes from the socket and hold them. As a result, you can only ever read the number of bytes equivalent to the size of your buffer at one time.

I often use a buffer of 4096 bytes. I've benchmarked it at 1024, 2048, and for fun, 100000. The performance wasn't much different between the arrays, but the memory usage did change due to the buffer size.

One best practice is to use a smaller buffer in order to read data from the socket more frequently, and depending on what you *do* with the data, potentially hold less data in memory at once as well. This keeps the socket from overflowing with queue'd data which has not been processed. What I mean is: if processing the bytes you receive takes 1 ms per byte, it's better to read 1024 bytes at once (~1 second between socket reads) than it would be to read 4096 bytes at once (~4 seconds between socket reads). More frequent reads of the socket data means less data queued at the socket.

**EDIT:** also worth noting, your loop will not always work currently. Whether or not data is available to read is happenstance and depends on many factors which you do not control such as WAN hops and delays in sending or receiving data. What you must do is use or invent a protocol that tells you how many bytes you expect to receive for a given message, and then read in the loop until either 1) you've received all expected bytes or 2) you reach a timeout at which point you feel it is taking too long. Your loop probably works currently because it's being done locally or over LAN, but it's not reliable and in fact prone to error.

Comment: @DavidHenry I could be wrong, but I believe my loop works because the server I am dealing with is a one-shot transaction server.  Open socket, make request, server returns data and immediately closes the socket.  Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @RobertOschler it's Haney, and nope. TCP is non-deterministic in buffered sends. For a 10 byte message it may arbitrarily send 1 bytes at a time 10 times, or 2 bytes 5 times, or 5 bytes, then 3 bytes, then 2 bytes, or any other combination, or even nothing for 5 seconds and then 9 bytes then 2 seconds of delay then the last byte. You must account for the *expected* number of bytes.

Comment: Sorry about that. Understood.  The data coming back from the server changes in length every time since it's a request for an audio file stream.  Fixed length, but only the server knows that.  What's a good technique for dealing with that?  Better question, is it possible for a client socket to get a disconnect event *before* all data has been received in the queue? If not, couldn't I just stay in a read loop until I detect a socket disconnect event?

Comment: It changes in length, and you will receive it in arbitrary chunks as well. You must create your own protocol: reserved bytes at the start of the message in Little Endian can be used to tell your client how many bytes will follow. As for the client disconnect: it may never receive such a notification. Often, you won't know that the server is done until you try to talk to the server again. I would not rely upon it.